# variadic list vs single template parameter: what does the standard say?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, standards-compliance, overload-resolution

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Variadic version
template<class... Variadic>
void f(const Variadic&... variadic)
{
    std::cout<<"variadic"<<std::endl;
}

// Single version
template<class Single, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<Single>::value>::type>
void f(const Single& single)
{
    std::cout<<"single"<<std::endl;
}

// Main
int main()
{
    f();              // variadic
    f(42);            // single : why?
    f(std::string()); // variadic 
    f(42, 42);        // variadic
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why the line marked "single" compiles well (under g++ 4.6.3) and does not produce an overload resolution problem. Does the c++11 standard say that a template function with a fixed number of parameters is prefered over a variadic function that could have the same signature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the use of the second, enable_if, template parameter in the 'single' version, the compiler considers that version to be a more-specialized template for use with the types for which it is enabled.

It is considered more specialized because there are types where the variadic template can be instantiated, but the 'single' can't.

The general rule is that a more specialized template trumps a less specialized template in overload resolution.

Comment: Note: the `enable_if` has nothing to do with the "Single" overload being more specialized, it's orthogonal and serves at *removing* the function from the set of possible overloads.

Comment: But when it doesn't remove the function, you get `f<int, void>(const int&)` which is more specialized than `f<int>(const int&)`. The fact the second template parameter is `enable_if` is not relevant. but the fact it has a second parameter is relevant, and is the reason that overload is chosen. Replacing the `enable_if` type with `void` makes that overload viable for `f(std::string())` and then it also gets selected for that call as more specialized.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree that that is the intent of using `enable_if`. As Jonathan explains, a side-effect of it is making the template more specialised for those cases where it is not removed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ooops, you are right, I was a bit hasty here.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Am I missing something?  You don't need a 2nd type parameter to make the single argument one win out on overload resolution.

Comment: @Yakk, I don't remember the details of the question or the point I was making, but I don't think I meant to suggest you necessarily _need_ a second template parameter to make it win, but as written the fact it does have one is relevant. Your recent answer is correct - but would change the result because `f(std::string())` would print  `"T\n"` as well.

Comment: @JonathanWakely This question seems to be coming back to haunt you :-). In your comments, you said that the fact that the function template has an additional *template* parameter is relevant for deciding which function template is *more specialized*. Could you elaborate on that, please? My reading of the standard suggests that's not the case. [14.8.2.4p3] says that the types used are those *function* parameter types for which the call has arguments. According to [14.8.2.4p11], a *template* parameter may even remain without a value when determining partial ordering. What am I missing?

Comment: @JonathanWakely If the additional *template* parameter were relevant, then replacing the variadic template overload with a non-variadic one taking only one template parameter and one function parameter (just remove the `...` everywhere) would still result in the second overload being chosen, right? That doesn't happen: the call `f(42)` becomes ambiguous. This strongly suggests it's the *function* parameter of the first overload being variadic that decides which template is more specialized, not the default *template* parameter of the second overload. Basically, Yakk's answer.

Answer (score 5):

[It is really](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e798a12713c2770) [quite simple](http://ideone.com/TKDvd7) (two live examples, gcc and clang)

```
template<class...T> void foo(T&&...) {std::cout << "...T\n";}
template<class T> void foo(T&&) {std::cout << "T\n";}
int main() {
  foo(3);
}
```

Overloads not taking `...` seem to be preferred when the choice is an explicit template parameter.

The `class=std::enable_if_t` does not change this.

So both your functions `f` are candidates, then the compiler prefers the one without variardics.

## 14.8.2.4 Deducing template arguments during partial ordering [temp.deduct.partial]

/8:

> If `A` was transformed from a function parameter pack and `P` is not a parameter pack, type deduction fails.  Otherwise, using the resulting types `P` and `A`, the deduction is then done as described in `14.8.2.5`. If `P` is a function parameter pack, the type `A` of each remaining parameter type of the argument template is compared with the type P of the declarator-id
>   of the function parameter pack. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function parameter pack. If deduction succeeds for a given type, the type from the argument template is considered to be at least as specialized as the type from the parameter template. [
>   Example:

```
template<class... Args> void f(Args... args); // #1
template<class T1, class... Args> void f(T1 a1, Args... args); // #2
template<class T1, class T2> void f(T1 a1, T2 a2); // #3
f(); // calls #1
f(1, 2, 3); // calls #2
f(1, 2); // calls #3; non-variadic template #3 is more
// specialized than the variadic templates #1 and #
```

In particular, the `f(1,2)` example.

All the `enable_if_t` clause does is remove the one-argument version from consideration when you pass a `std::string` as `T`.